# Cross-ratio of Conics on a pencil of conics

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry, plane-geometry

Let $C_1, C_2, C_3$ be the three split conics in a simple pencil $L$ of conics on $\mathbb{P}_2$, with $a,b,c,d$ as its four base points. For an arbitrary conic $C \in L$, how can I compute the cross-ratio $[C_1, C_2, C_3, C]$ on $L$. And how will that compare to the cross-ratio $[a,b,c,d]$ on $C$?

Comment: Can't you compute both?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how to compute the cross-ration of conics on the pencil

Comment: Choose your favorite 4 points and parameterize the pencil of conics through it.

Comment: If I let $a,b,c,d$ be those points. Then the equations of the pencil $L$ will be $\frac{\det(x,a,b)\cdot \det(x,c,d)}{\det(x,a,c)\cdot \det(x,b,d)}=\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_1}$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Choose some coordinates.

Comment: Your question was very interesting.  Was it part of a course or textbook?

Answer (score 2):

The paper [Thomas, *Geometric Characterizations Of The Cross Ratio In A Pencil Of Conics*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.03811.pdf) talks about this.  There are several ways to compute a cross ratio of conics, but I picked out this one (pg 11):

> **Corollary 1.** The cross ratio of four conics in a pencil is given by the cross ratio of the four tangents at a base point.

If conics $C_1,C_2,C_3$ are the degenerate conics of the pencil, I found that

$$
[C_1, C_2, C_3, C] = [a,b,c,d]_C
$$

This notion of taking cross ratios in a pencil of conics goes back at least to the 19th century.  E.g. see [Chasles, *Sections Coniques*, 1865, Art 325](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_k6gvUxken8IC/page/n225/mode/2up?view=theater), where the cross ratio ("rapport anharmonique") of the four polars of a point is used. (See also [Milne, *Cross Ratio Geometry*, Art 220](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.90533/page/n233/mode/2up?view=theater).)

The general expression for a pencil of entities (points, lines, conics, whatever) is $A+\lambda B$, where $A,B$ are members of the pencil.

The cross ratio of $A+kB,A+lB,A+mB,A+nB$ is
$\dfrac{(n-l)(m-k)}{(n-m)(l-k)}$.  For details see [Salmon, *Conic Sections*, Art. 58](https://archive.org/details/atreatiseonconi09salmgoog/page/n76/mode/2up?q=%22anharmonic%20ratio%22&view=theater).